# XPath keep track of data from every table

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I've been digging into a website for some time :

http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution

I need to extract data under Master's from each University.

As you may notice not every University has Master's data, so I need to keep track of it.

How can I keep track of the data in this situation?

My python with XPATH code so far :

```
import __future__
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution')

soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser'))

tree = html.fromstring(soup)

for table in tree.xpath('//table[@width="95%" and @align="center" and @class="center"]'):
    print('-- NEW TABLE -- \n')
    tab = table.xpath('.//table[@width="260px"]/tr/td[@style="width: 100%;"]/text()')
    print(tab)

print('Ready !!')
```

As you see it prints `-- NEW TABLE --` but the `tab` variable is an empty array.

The `tab` variable should have been consisted of the data under **Baccalaureate**, **Master's** and **Doctor of Nursing Practice** of each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for table in tree.xpath('(//tr[ td[span="Baccalaureate"] or td[contains(span,"Master")] ]/ancestor::tr[1])'):
  print('-- NEW TABLE -- \n')
  tab = table.xpath('.//table[@width="260px"]/tr/td[@style="width: 100%;"]/text()')
  print(tab)
```

Comment: It works like a charm.
Just help me understand this.
why did you put: `ancestor::tr[1]` ?
And why you put the `td` as an index of `tr` like `tr[ td ... ]`

Comment: `tr[ td ... ]` finds the tr with the data you are looking for. `ancestor::tr[1]`  finds the next tr above this one. This tr holds all your data for one university.

Comment: But why isn't it working like `tr/td[ ... ]` ? why `td` must be an index of `tr` ?

As you see the `tab`'s variable xpath it's different... why?

Comment: Because `tr[ td ... ]` ( tr expression with and predicates ) finds the `tr` but `tr/td[ ... ]` finds a `td` (tr/td is the expression now). And than the  first ancestor  is not the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath to extract Master's Data.

```
//span[contains(text(),'Master')]/parent::td[1]
```